# google wifi Access Point geo location by MAC

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I found on certain web site that it is possible to find location of wifi Access Point location by providing MAC address.

my question is : what is the name of API used for that , and what api do i use to get wifi AP location from MAc address (on windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Google's [Geolocation API Network Protocol](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/gears/geolocation_network_protocol.html).

There you can see the example JSON object like that:

```
"wifi_towers": [
    {
      "mac_address": "01-23-45-67-89-ab",
      "signal_strength": 8,
      "age": 0
    },
    {
      "mac_address": "01-23-45-67-89-ac",
      "signal_strength": 4,
      "age": 0
    }
  ]
```

****Google Gears API is no longer available**